# Border-Radius Bug in Chrome on an Object with Opacity Keyframes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm getting a border-radius bug on the latest version of Chrome (working properly on Firefox) that lasts the time of an animation that uses opacity on a **div** from an HTML page [**b. html**] inserted in another HTML page [**a. html**] with **object**.

I tried other solutions (jQuery, Web Components...) without getting what I wanted and I honestly preferred to stay with **object** for this particular project even though it is an aging technology.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3za3.png)

**a.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <object id="b" data="b.html"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

**b.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hi, how are you?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body { background: blue; }

#b {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-radius: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    height: 400px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    animation: ani 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes ani {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just as example, here is the jQuery version I found [**a.html**]

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#b").load("b.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="b"></div>
</body>
</html>
```